# How to change Module PSini to other way to read file in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I read INI file with this module PSIni. In some reason, I don't want to use that module to read my file. Is there any way to do it?

This code is work with module PSIni.

```
Function Write-File
{
    Param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]$FilePath,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $a,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $b,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $c
    )
    Import-Module PsIni
    $file1 = Get-IniContent $FilePath
    $file1["$a"]["$b"] = "$c"  
    $file1 | Out-IniFile -FilePath $FilePath -Force
}
```

I try this code without that module. But It's not working.

```
Function Write-File
{
    Param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]$FilePath,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $a,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $b,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $c
    )

    $file1 = Get-Content $FilePath
    $file1["$a"]["$b"] = "$c"  
    $file1 | Out-File -FilePath $FilePath -Force
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to use WindowsAPI.

```
$src = @"
[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL")]
public static extern uint GetPrivateProfileString(string lpAppName, string lpKeyName, string lpDefault, System.Text.StringBuilder lpReturnedString, uint nSize, string lpFileName);
[DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL")]
public static extern uint WritePrivateProfileString(string lpAppName, string lpKeyName, string lpString, string lpFileName);
"@

Add-Type -MemberDefinition $src -Namespace WinApi -Name IniFileIO -Language CSharp

Function Read-IniFile ($Path, $Section, $Key) {
    $sb = [Text.StringBuilder]::new(1024)
    [WinApi.IniFileIO]::GetPrivateProfileString($Section, $Key, $null, $sb, $sb.Capacity, (Convert-Path -LiteralPath $Path)) > $null
    $sb.ToString()
}

Function Write-IniFile ($Path, $Section, $Key, $Value) {
    [WinApi.IniFileIO]::WritePrivateProfileString($Section, $Key, $Value, (Convert-Path -LiteralPath $Path)) >$null
}
```

The usage is as follows.

```
Read-IniFile -Path "C:\sample.ini" -Section "Section1" -Key "Key1"
Write-IniFile -Path "C:\sample.ini" -Section "Section2" -Key "Key2" -Value "Hello"
```

This is casual code, so it is better to use [the code written by mklement0](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/006c2352ddae7bb05693be028240f5b6) for actual use. It is more robust.

Comment: wow. Thank you... But how do I use this way, If I want to do remove the section ?

Comment: For example, `Set-IniValue -LiteralPath sample.ini -Section Section1` removes the "Section1" section.
`Set-IniValue -LiteralPath sample.ini -Section Section2 -Key Key1` removes "Key1" which is the key of "Section2".